# tilt-shift with three.js depth of field bokeh shader

Tags: three.js, depth, post-processing

Three.js comes with [a great depth of field example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_postprocessing_dof.html) which I've been using in a project and it works nice.

What i'd like to do is modify it so that the bokeh works in front AND behind of the focal point, tilt-shift style.

I'm pretty new to this stuff but it looks like what I'd need to do is have it calculate the depth texture from a camera point in front of the camera (the example calculates it from the current camera position) but no matter what I try I can't get that to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok nvm, the "focus" uniform is what I wanted, you get the focal point in front of the camera if you make it < 1 - I just didn't realise it before because the steps required are minute, in my scene placing the focal point at the scene's center requires a focus value of 0.98, and the example GUI was moving the focal length by steps of 0.025

Comment: But wait: YES I can move the focus in front of the camera; but the way that works out mathematically is that you will only get a minor blur effect between the camera and the focal point compared to the blur effect you'll get AFTER the focal point - because the distance to the focal point might be only 100 units whereas the fov after the focal point might stretch off to 10000 times that. So how would I modify the shader (I guess?) to provide the classic tilt-shift of very narrow DOF with visually equivalent blur on either side?